# COBOL File Directory Not Found

Tags: file, directory, cobol

I have a COBOL program (CH5PPB.cblproj) that attempts to read CH5PP.DAT with no success; the file is not found. I have tried the following ASSIGN lines separately.

Each run gives me a COBOL FileHandlingException of 13 File not found. I've tried googling the problem, to no effect. Furthermore, all my COBOL programs that attempt to access a file has the same problem. I've tried running with and without debugging.

```
       SELECT IN-EMPLOYEE-FILE
           ASSIGN TO 'CH5PP.DAT'
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

       SELECT IN-EMPLOYEE-FILE
           ASSIGN TO 'C:\Users\nsacket\Desktop\COBOL TEXTBOOK FILES\ch05\CH5PPB\CH5PPB\CH5PP.DAT'
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

       SELECT IN-EMPLOYEE-FILE
           ASSIGN TO 'C:\CH5PP.DAT'
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
```

Comment: What Cobol are you using? Is your file in C:\ or in the directory you are running from, or what? If you open an output file and write to it, where does the file get created?

Answer (score 0):

have the issue resolved or still you facing the issue. You have not provided the information what COBOL you are using. It seems your are using Micro Focus COBOL Visual Studio project ?

Remove the ' quote from ASSIGN TO 'CH5PP.DAT' it is should be ASSIGN TO CH5PP.DAT

And if you are trying to read this file this file should be default placed in load folder if not set via environment variable.

Also avoid using the path like

> ASSIGN TO 'C:\Users\nsacket\Desktop\COBOL TEXTBOOK FILES\

Spaces in COBOL TEXTBOOK Files can make your life difficult.